# PHP: Make Site Unicode Compatible

Tags: php, language-agnostic, unicode, utf-8

How can i make my site unicode compatible to support more languages other than english.

Thanks

Comment: You just need to use a Unicode character encoding. That’s it.

Comment: FYI don't ask the same question multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For PHP:

First of all you need to set your scripts  encoding to utf8 (IDEs/Editors like Eclipse/Notepass++ or Ultraedit are able of this). If you will output xhtml then you maybe add:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="application/xhtml+xml;charset=utf-8" />
    </head>
```

to force the browser to use utf8.

If youre working with for example xml documents, databases(many of them support utf8) or any other sources which are not utf8 than have a look at following functions for conversion in the php documentation:

```
string utf8_encode  ( string $data  );
string utf8_decode  ( string $data  );

string iconv  ( string $in_charset  , string $out_charset  , string $str  );
```

Here the links to the documentation:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.iconv.php

As an addition try:

http://de.php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php